# Regular expression for positive decimal value and -1 value in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

How do a Regular expression for positive decimal value and -1 value in jquery?
I managed to do it for positive and negative decimal value with this, but it can only be -1. Any idea?

```
$(".SermeCoopValidarTope").keypress(function (e) {
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    var numeroDecimal = $(this).val();
    if (tecla == 8) return true;

    if (tecla > 47 && tecla < 58) {
        if (numeroDecimal == "") return true
        regexp = /^([0-9])*[.]?[0-9]{0,1}$/;
        return (regexp.test(numeroDecimal))
    }
    if (tecla == 46) {
        if (numeroDecimal == "") return false
        regexp = /^[0-9]+$/
        return regexp.test(numeroDecimal)
    }
    return false
});
```

Comment: Do you have a small mockup of this to provide a complete test against?

Comment: Just realised the current logic is slightly broken... I changed the logic to create the expected string first, then test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use or `|` with two matching expressions to test for either/or match.

I also re-wrote the code to construct the expected value, based on current value and new keypress. This simplifed the code a lot.

```
$(".SermeCoopValidarTope").keypress(function (e) {
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    var numeroDecimal = $(this).val();

    // Allow backspace
    if (tecla == 8) return true;

    // if it's a valid character, append it to the value
    if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58) || tecla == 45 || tecla == 46) {
        numeroDecimal += String.fromCharCode(tecla)
    }
    else return false;

    // Now test to see if the result "will" be valid (if the key were allowed)

    regexp = /^\-1?$|^([0-9])*[.]?[0-9]{0,2}$/;
    return (regexp.test(numeroDecimal));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ld3n4b56/

Update to support `,` instead of `.` for the decimal separator:

```
$(".SermeCoopValidarTope").keypress(function (e) {
    var tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    var numeroDecimal = $(this).val();

    // Allow backspace
    if (tecla == 8) return true;

    // if it's a valid character, append it to the value
    if ((tecla > 47 && tecla < 58) || tecla == 45 || tecla == 44) {
        numeroDecimal += String.fromCharCode(tecla)
    }
    else return false;

    // Now test to seee of the result will be valid

    regexp = /^\-1?$|^([0-9])*[,]?[0-9]{0,2}$/;
    return (regexp.test(numeroDecimal));
});
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ld3n4b56/1/

Shortened versions of the RegEx (thanks to @Brian Stephens):

Period decimal separator: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld3n4b56/4/

```
/^(-1?|\d*.?\d{0,2})$/
```

Comma decimal separator: http://jsfiddle.net/Ld3n4b56/3/

```
/^(-1?|\d*,?\d{0,2})$/
```

Comment: Thanks! but Does not allow me to type '-' in my TextBox

Comment: @Eduardo Pedrosa Barrero: That's because you only accept specific keypresses and ignore the rest (including minus = 45). Just add it to the `if (tecla > 47 && tecla < 58 || tecla == 45) {

Comment: Thanks TrueBlueAussie, now if i type '-'  does not allow me to type any, also, allow me type a number and '-' Example: '3-'

Comment: @Eduardo Pedrosa Barrero: Too quick tiger :) Answer updated. I rewrote it to be simpler.

Comment: Sorry for abuse :), one last thing ... How can I change the decimal separator? I want to be ','

Comment: @Eduardo Pedrosa Barrero: http://www.asciitable.com/ Just change the `46` to `44` and the `[.]` to `[,]` Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Ld3n4b56/1/

Comment: Why propagate the OP's unnecessary characters in the regex? Simplify. The `/^\-1?$|^([0-9])*[,]?[0-9]{0,2}$/` in your answer could be reduced to `/^(-1?|\d*,?\d{0,2})$/`.

Comment: @Brian Stephens: I must have miss-copied it last time. Have added to answer and will delete irrelvant comments. Thanks,

Comment: One more little problem: the version for a period separator needs to escape the period. Then I think it's all good!

Comment: @Brian Stephens: Might be the sequence interprets it correctly based on placement, but the period version appears to work fine without escaping (see that JSFiddle).

Comment: A dot must be escaped in a regex to match only a literal period. Otherwise, it matches any character. The only reason it (mostly) works in this case is because only certain ASCII characters are allowed as input. Try `1-1` and you'll see that it allows a dash in that position.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|` (or operator):

```
/^([0-9]+|-1)$/ or simply /^(\d+|-1)$/
```

Also I suggest you to change your regex `/^([0-9])*[.]?[0-9]{0,1}$/` to

```
/^([0-9])*(\.[0-9])?$/ or simply /^\d*(\.\d)?$/
```

For making it more meaningful and to not allow values like `123.` (ending with dot) or just `.`

Comment: Thanks! but Does not allow me to type '-' in my TextBox:

Comment: The logic of the original code was always testing *one character behind* the actual requirement. The whole thing needed an overhaul to do what was really needed (allow -1 or a decimal with up to 2 decimal places). Otherwise it allows double periods etc.